# Append special character to Excel Cell with Macro

Tags: excel, vba

i have created a macro in excel in which i open a csv file and make some changes that works fine. But i am stuck in what i want to do next.
I want to add the " character at the beginning and the end of the column K with keeping the content.

Any idea how can i do this ?
Thanks in advance.

here is the code that i have tried :

```
 Columns("K").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Dim k As Range
    For Each k In Range("K2", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    k.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(k.Text, "0000000000")
    k.Value = Chr(34) & k.Value & Chr(34)
  Next k
```

but i get the value of the k column like this : """0000062447"""

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You mean the basic `val = """" & val & """"` (in a loop on range or array, array being the better choice) or `val = chr(34) & val & chr(34)`

Comment: tried this :
Columns("K").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Dim k As Range
    For Each k In Range("K2", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    k.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(k.Text, "0000000000")
    k.Value = Chr(34) & k.Value & Chr(34)
  Next k

but i get the numbers like this : """0000062447"""

Comment: Sadly, this is behaving as per Microsoft's design for writing CSV files. It's not really possible to get it to perform differently. You may want to consider writing your own export program.

Answer (score 0):

This will apply the double quotes just the once, and if run again will ignore any cells already double quoted:

```
Columns("K").NumberFormat = "@"
Dim k As Range
For Each k In Range("K2", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not (Left(k.Value, 1) = Chr(34) And Right(k.Value, 1) = Chr(34)) Then
        k.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(k.Text, "0000000000")
        k.Value = Chr(34) & k.Value & Chr(34)
    End If
Next k
```

Input:

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: tried and still the same outcome

Comment: There must be something else at play here, the code you've provided - and that I've altered slightly - does exactly what you've asked for.

Comment: maybe because i use a csv file to read the data ?

Comment: actually the excel i created has a button which when pressed it asks the user to select a csv file to open and create a new csv file which makes the changes i said

Comment: Ah, okay. This is an issue with the built in CSV export function in Excel, nothing wrong with the cell contents.